# WCF Rest weird routing behavior

Tags: wcf, rest, routes

I have a resource available at
http://localhost/resource

I do not have any route like
http:/localhost/resource?name=john

but when I try to hit the above URI I get the result of http://localhost/resource. I was expecting a 404.

Any idea why its ignoring ?name=john and match the url ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query string parameters are optional and not "officially" part of the address - it goes from the scheme to the path (via host and port). There are many scenarios where you have one operation at address http://something.com/path, and *in the operation code* you look at the query string parameters to make some decision. For example, the code below looks for a "format" parameter in the query string which may or may not be passed, and all requests (with or without it) are correctly routed to the operation.

```
public class StackOverflow_10422764
{
    [DataContract(Name = "Person", Namespace = "")]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/NoQueryParams")]
        public Person GetPerson()
        {
            string format = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["format"];
            if (format == "xml")
            {
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Xml;
            }
            else if (format == "json")
            {
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
            }

            return new Person { Name = "Scooby Doo", Age = 10 };
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/NoQueryParams"));

        c = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/NoQueryParams?format=json"));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

**Update after comments**:
If you want to force the request to contain exactly the parameters specified in the template, then you can use something like a message inspector to validate that.

```
public class StackOverflow_10422764
{
    [DataContract(Name = "Person", Namespace = "")]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/NoQueryParams")]
        public Person GetPerson()
        {
            string format = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["format"];
            if (format == "xml")
            {
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Xml;
            }
            else if (format == "json")
            {
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
            }

            return new Person { Name = "Scooby Doo", Age = 10 };
        }

        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/TwoQueryParam?x={x}&y={y}")]
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
    public class MyForceQueryMatchBehavior : IEndpointBehavior, IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        #region IEndpointBehavior Members

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDispatchMessageInspector Members

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            UriTemplateMatch uriTemplateMatch = (UriTemplateMatch)request.Properties["UriTemplateMatchResults"];

            // TODO: may need to deal with the case of implicit UriTemplates, or if you want to allow for some query parameters to be ommitted

            List<string> uriTemplateQueryVariables = uriTemplateMatch.Template.QueryValueVariableNames.Select(x => x.ToLowerInvariant()).ToList();
            List<string> requestQueryVariables = uriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters.Keys.OfType<string>().Select(x => x.ToLowerInvariant()).ToList();
            if (uriTemplateQueryVariables.Count != requestQueryVariables.Count || uriTemplateQueryVariables.Except(requestQueryVariables).Count() > 0)
            {
                throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
        }

        #endregion
    }
    static void SendRequest(string uri)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Request to {0}", uri);
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}", c.DownloadString(uri));
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = e.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            Console.WriteLine("  ERROR => {0}", resp.StatusCode);
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Service), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyForceQueryMatchBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        SendRequest(baseAddress + "/NoQueryParams");
        SendRequest(baseAddress + "/NoQueryParams?format=json");
        SendRequest(baseAddress + "/TwoQueryParam?x=7&y=9&z=other");
        SendRequest(baseAddress + "/TwoQueryParam?x=7&y=9");

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this... however is it possible to configure it such that if there is not 100% match on a URI template respond with some kind of error?

Comment: Just to clarify the statement "Query string parameters are optional and not "officially" part of the address".  You mean the WCF REST framework does not consider the query string parameters as "part of the address".  However, according to the URI spec http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt query string parameters are part of the identification of a resource.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Thanks for your comment. I was kinda re-thinking my REST concepts because of how its behaving. It is funny that even FB api works the way my api works. However I guess thats a good behavior for a MVC app.. but for a restful api i was thinking 1 URI pattern = resource. I wonder how OpenRasta and ServiceStack handle this

Comment: @Perpetualcoder, you could do that with something like a message inspector, which would compare the query variables from the template with the ones from the request, and fail if they didn't match. I've updated the answer with this option as well.